# How to install qt 5.9.7 using brew in macOS high Sierra?

Tags: qt, homebrew, macos-high-sierra

brew install qt@5.9.7
Updating Homebrew...
To restore the stashed changes to /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core, run:
cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core && git stash pop
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> Updated Formulae
Updated 1 formula.

==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
Error: No available formula or cask with the name "qt@5.9.7".
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.

Comment: What is your question? Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I think the question is how to get version 5.9.7 installed on his mac. I was able to reproduce the issue. Im trying to get the same version installed on my machine as well and I get the same error. I know they recently archived this version.  https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.9/

Comment: Looks like 5.9 is no longer avaliable https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/qt#default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like 5.9 is not support for home brew you will need the dmg

https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.9/5.9.7/

If you want to build and install yourself here are the steps. This is what I needed to do

https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.9/osx-building.html